# DateTimeFormatter parseBest() gives ' could not be parsed at index 8' exception

Tags: date, datetime, time, java-8, dateformatter

I am a little confused about how the parseBest method works.
I have a formatter pattern and i am parsing the date with the parseBest method as follows:

```
    DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd['T'HH:mm:ss[Z]]");
    parseMyDate(parser, "2016-12-07");
    parseMyDate(parser, "2016-12-07T15:31:12");
    parseMyDate(parser, "2016-12-07T15:31:12-0500");
    parseMyDate(parser, "2016-12-07Hello");

    public static void parseMyDate(DateTimeFormatter formatter, String parseText) {
    try {
      TemporalAccessor ta = formatter.parseBest(parseText, 
                                                OffsetDateTime::from,
                                                LocalDateTime::from, 
                                                LocalDate::from);
      if (ta instanceof OffsetDateTime) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.from(ta);
        System.out.println("OffsetDateTime: " + odt);
      } else if (ta instanceof LocalDateTime) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.from(ta);
        System.out.println("LocalDateTime: " + ldt);
      } else if (ta instanceof LocalDate) {
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.from(ta);
        System.out.println("LocalDate: " + ld);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Parsing returned: " + ta);
      }
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
      System.out.println("Here in Exception : "+e.getMessage());
      //e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

But for all for method calls, i got the same exception as follows:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-12-07Hello' could not be parsed at index 8
>       at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
>       at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseBest(DateTimeFormatter.java:1897)
>       at com.my.j8.DataTime.parseStr(DataTime.java:164)
>       at com.my.j8.DataTime.main(DataTime.java:158)

I tried changing the pattern as follows:
     DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM- dd");

But still no luck. Any suggestion?

Comment: Apart being down voted, not deleting the question as this piece of code may help someone in doing some good/best parsing exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space in your pattern before the `-dd` so none of your dates match the pattern - the match has to be exact.

A pattern of `"yyyy-MM-dd['T'HH:mm:ss[Z]]"` (without the space) works for your first 3 patterns.

The last pattern still fails because the pattern does not match `Hello` - the pattern must match the entire input string.